# how to send data in ping program

Tags: tcp, loopback

I wanted to send data to the loop-back IP address 127.0.0.1 using the ping program.
$ping 127.0.0.1 "my data" and wanted to see it in the kernel space.
if anyone has some idea please respond to me

Comment: Is this purely academic or are you actually trying to carry a payload?  There are much better ways to send data to the local machine.

Comment: Might be one of those data exilfration techniques like DNS tunneling, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use ping's `-p` option:

> -p pattern
>               You may specify up to 16 ``pad'' bytes to fill out the packet you send.
>      This is useful for  diagnosing data-dependent  problems in a network.
>      For example, *-p ff* will cause the sent packet to be filled with all ones.